# Cannot break the forloop

Tags: c++

How can I break the forloop after it reads all the input? right now it does not stop running.
The program is taking inout integers from 0 to 10 and writes down the word for them. the problem is that even if it reads all the inputs it is still running. I am looking for a solution to stop it from running after it reads and prints all the words for the inputs.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <array>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {

 int i;
 int digits;

 for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {  
     cin >> digits;
        
     const char *str [] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
        
     switch(digits) {
         case 0: cout << str[0] << endl;
             break;
         case 4: cout << str[4] << endl;
             break;
         case 5: cout << str[5] << endl;
             break;
         case 6: cout << str[6] << endl;
             break;
         case 7: cout << str[7] << endl;
             break;   
         case 1: cout << str[1] << endl;
             break;
         case 2: cout << str[2] << endl;
             break;
         case 3: cout << str[3] << endl;
             break;
         case 8: cout << str[8] << endl;
             break;
         case 9: cout << str[9] << endl;
             break;
         }                               
     }
     return 0;      
 }
```

Comment: Btw, you could probably replace the whole switch/case block with something like `if ((digits>=0)&&(digits<=9)) cout << str[digits] << endl;` and still get the same behavior.

Comment: you currently break out of the switch

Comment: Why the seemingly random order to your `case` statements? Looks like a headache for code maintenance.

Comment: *"How can I break the forloop after it reads all the input?"* -- how can you know when all the input has been read? Are you guaranteed exactly 11 inputs? What is the input you are trying to provide?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for the answer, I used your method which does the same thing as mine, I want the program to stop after we press the enter. Now it is still going after we press the enter button.

Comment: @SaidShah It's looking like most of your example code is noise. It looks like your real question is how to tell when the user presses enter after entering a sequence of numbers. Your current non-working [mre] might be the following: `#include <iostream> int main() { int i; int digits; for(i = 0; i <= 10; i++) { std::cin >> digits; /* Do stuff */ } return 0; }`. By removing things extraneous to your core question, you help answers focus on your core question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your program to read *up to* ten digits (i.e. have it stop running if it encounters EOF before ten digits have been read), you could do it like this:

```
for(i = 0; ((i < 10)&&(cin >> digits)); i++) { 
   const char *str [] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
   if ((digits>=0)&&(digits<=9)) cout << str[digits] << endl;
}
```

Note that the `>>` operator on `cin` will return false on failure/EOF, which will cause your for-loop stop iterating at that point.

Comment: Hi there, I used your method and it is working prefectly, but the problem is the program is open after one entry or multiple. I want it to stop once we press the enter.

Comment: The `<<` operator doesn't have a facility for detecting newline characters -- it treats spaces and carriage-return/newline as interchangeable.  If you want to just parse the contents of a single line, you'll need a different approach, e.g. calling `std::getline(cin, myString);` and then parsing out the contents of the `std::string myString;` object afterwards.

Comment: FWIW on most OS's if you are typing on a terminal to feed the program's stdin, you can send an EOF signal by pressing control-D.   (Or you can feed the program's stdin non-interactively e.g. `echo "1 2 3 4" | ./my_program` and your program's stdin will get an EOF at the end of the passed-in string)

Answer (score 0):

your `for` loop runs for 11 cycles, not for 10. This is probably why you see it is not ending at the end. you need to use `i < 10`. Not sure why you used this huge switch as well. Here is an example and it exits the loop after 10 inputs.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int i;
  int digits;
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {  
    cin >> digits;
            
    const char *str [] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", 
                          "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
    if (digits >= 0 && digits < 10)
        cout << str[digits] << endl;
                    
  }
  return 0;      
}
```